# The product rule of probability - Specific rewriting

Tags: probability, bayesian

So, the product rule of probability states

> > $$ p(X,Y) = p(X|Y)*p(Y) $$
> >     In general for any set of variables:
> >     $$ p(X_1, X_2, ..., X_N) = \prod_{n=1}^N p(X_n|X_1, X_2, ..., X_{n-1})$$

Now, an example from my textbook is given immediately after this:

> > For example: $p(X, Y, Z) = p(X)*p(Y|X)*p(Z|Y,X)$

I don't understand why $p(X,Y,Z)$ is equal to the above, and not $$p(X,Y,Z) = p(X|Y,Z)*p(Y|X,Z)*p(Z|Y,X)$$

Are they the same?

Comment: The notation is strange.  Which textbook is this?

Comment: Well it's actually from lecture slides in a machine learning course. Curious to know what you find strange about it?

Comment: Capital letters, e.g. $X$ and $Y$ as used here, usually denote random variables, so $p(X,Y)$ becomes another random variable.  If $X$ and $Y$ are discrete, $P(X=x \cap Y=y)$ (a function of $x$ and $y$) would be more standard notation or $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ for the joint pdf if $X,Y$ are continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$p(X, Y, Z) = p(X)*p(Y|X)*p(Z|Y,X)$$ because when you plug in $X, Y, Z$ in your formula ($X_1=X, X_2=Y, X_3=Z$)

You get that

$$ p(X, Y, Z) = p(X_1, X_2, X_3) = $$

$$\prod_{n=1}^3 p(X_n|X_1, X_2, ..., X_{n-1}) = P(X_3 | X_1, X_2)P(X_2|X_1)P(X_1) = $$

$$P(Z | X, Y)P(Y|X)P(X) = p(X)p(Y|X)p(Z|Y,X)$$

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same.

You can group random variables and treat them as one: let $(X,Y)=T$

$$P(X,Y,Z)=P(T,Z)=P(T)P(Z|T)$$

Replace $T$:

$$P(X,Y,Z)=P(X,Y)P(Z|X,Y)$$

and place the usual expansion of $P(X,Y)$ in which you get the formula you need.